# Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$id Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5, shopping-cart

What I want to is add a product to the shopping cart. After i click add to cart button , i get the undefined property error. I take this code from https://www.codetutorial.io/the-shopping-cart-how-to-craft-an-e-shop-with-laravel/. Can someone clarify what is the error. Thanks :)

**Product.blade.php**

```
  @foreach ($id as $id)
    <div class="caption">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
      <h3>{{$id->name}}</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 price">
       <h3>
       <label>RM {{$id->price}}</label></h3>
         </div>
     <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
     <a href="{{ route('addProduct',$id->product_id) }}" class="btn btn-
     success btn-product"><span class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></span>Add to 
     Cart</a></div>
         </div>
         </div>
           </div>
           </div>
          @endforeach
```

**CartController.php**

```
public function __construct()
{$this->middleware('auth');}

public function addItem ($productId){

   $cart = Cart::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id);

   if(!$cart){
       $cart =  new Cart();
       $cart->user_id=Auth::user()->id;
       $cart->save();
   }

   $cartItem  = new Cartitem();
   $cartItem->product_id=$productId;
   $cartItem->cart_id= $cart->id;
   $cartItem->save();
   return redirect('/viewcart');
   }


 public function showCart(){

 $cart = Cart::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id);

   if(!$cart){
       $cart =  new Cart();
       $cart->user_id=Auth::user()->id;
       $cart->save();
   }

   $items = $cart->cartItems;
   $total=0;
   foreach($items as $item){
       $total+=$item->product->price;
   }

   return view('viewcart',['items'=>$items,'total'=>$total]);}
```

**Viewcart.blade.php**

```
 @foreach ($items as $item)

 <tr><td class="col-sm-8 col-md-6"> <div class="media">
 <a class="thumbnail pull-left" href="#"> <img class="media-object" src="
 {{$item->product->image}}" style="width: 100px; height: 72px;"> </a>
 <div class="media-body">
 <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="#">{{$item->product->name}}</a></h4>
 </div></div></td>    
 <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center"><strong>{{$item->product>price}}
  </strong></td>
 <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1">
 <a href="/removeItem/{{$item->id}}"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-
 danger">
 <span class="fa fa-remove"></span> Remove
  </button></a></td></tr>
      @endforeach
```

**Update**
[cart_items database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ABXH.png)

Comment: `$cart = Cart::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->get();` try this

Comment: i manage get this error Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance. in this line :- $cartItem->cart_id= $cart->id;

Comment: are you sure there is data in cart ?

Comment: Yes there is , the data appear in my database. You can refer the image that i upload just now.

Comment: having data in database doesnt mean you have in your $cart try `dd($cart)`

Comment: Sorry im still new in laravel. i get this error - Can't use function return value in write context